# $cookieStore or $cookies is not saving $stateParams data

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

Below is my controller which I need to save `$stateParams` data in the `$cookieStore` or `$cookie`. Because when I refresh all the data in `$stateParams` is gone.

Below is how I did it. But it is not saving data. When I put a console.log all are becoming null.

```
        var userId = $stateParams.userId;
        $cookies.userName = userId;

        $cookieStore.put('userId', userId);
        $cookieStore.put('appId', $stateParams.appId);
        $cookieStore.put('tempUrl', $stateParams.tempUrl);
        $cookieStore.put('tempName', $stateParams.tempName);
        $cookieStore.put('tempCategory', $stateParams.tempCategory);

        $scope.userId = $cookies.userName;
        $scope.appId = $cookieStore.get('appId');
        $scope.tempUrl = $cookieStore.get('tempUrl');
        $scope.tempName = $cookieStore.get('tempName');
        $scope.tempCategory = $cookieStore.get('tempCategory');

        console.log($scope.userId);
        console.log($scope.appId);
        console.log($scope.tempUrl);
        console.log($scope.tempName);
        console.log($scope.tempCategory);
```

When I visit the page for the first time data is there. But when I refresh the page, all the consoles are becoming null.

Comment: There are no errors on your console except that?

Comment: no, only my consoles are becoming null so I can't proceed with other functions which I need this $stateParams data

Comment: Have you checked the stateParams values as well before they are fed to the cookie because I cannot see anything wrong with the cookie code.

Comment: Just enter values via directly $scope to the cookies, I think it'll work

Comment: Yes as I said the consoles print data when I visit the page for the first time

Comment: Gandalf the White, I didn't get what you said

Comment: `$cookieStore.put('appId', $scope.appId);` Try this

Comment: No it is not working either. Is it because it is in the same controller

Comment: Try making a fiddle in that case because there isn't anything wrong with cookie store code http://jsfiddle.net/mmendelson/qU56y/